# Subset a data.frame according to elements in a column

Tags: r

I have a data.frame that looks like this:

> ```
>  A     name_a    
>  A     name_a    
>  A     name_a    
>  B     name_b
>  B     name_b
>  B     name_b
>  C     name_c
>  C     name_c
>  C     name_c
> ```

I would like the following output:

> ```
>  A     name_a    
>  B     name_b    
>  C     name_c
> ```

I used the following string:

> ```
> df_subsetted = df[unique(df[,2]), ]
> ```

but it seems not to work. What can I try next?

Comment: You are probably looking for `df[!duplicated(df[, 2]),]`. `unique` doesn't return a logical vector,

Comment: `unique(df)` would also work